# How lower bound selectivity and high bound selectivity calculates in adaptive cursor sharing?

Tags: oracle, database-performance, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

How lower bound selectivity and high bound selectivity calculate in adaptive cursor sharing?

I've searched this on Google, but couldn't find a proper answer.

Comment: Without an actual code example to illustrate the question, this question looks too broad.